# Why does SDL2 display the dialog messages before the last printf? Very interesting

Tags: c, graphics, sdl-2

I can not figure out why the dialog messages get displayed before the "printf" statement.

If I add a '\n' to the "printf" than it acts like normal, but without it the dialog boxs ends up being displayed before the "printf".

Here is the test program:

```
/* Build: gcc -o test `sdl2-config --libs --cflags` test.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

void MessageBox(void);
void clean(void);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    atexit(clean);
    SDL_DisplayMode mode;
    int id = 0;
    SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode(id, &mode);
    char smode[20];
    sprintf(smode, "%ix%i@%iHz", mode.h, mode.w, mode.refresh_rate);
    printf("%s", smode);

    MessageBox();

    SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(SDL_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR,
            "Missing file",
            "File is missing. Please reinstall the program.",
            NULL
            );
    return(0);
}

void MessageBox() {
    const SDL_MessageBoxButtonData buttons[] ={ /* .flags, .buttonid, .text */
        {0, 0, "no"},
        {SDL_MESSAGEBOX_BUTTON_RETURNKEY_DEFAULT, 1, "yes" },
        { SDL_MESSAGEBOX_BUTTON_ESCAPEKEY_DEFAULT, 2, "cancel" },
        };

    const SDL_MessageBoxColorScheme colorScheme = { /* .colors (.r, .g, .b) */
        {   /* [SDL_MESSAGEBOX_COLOR_BACKGROUND] */
            { 0, 0, 0 },
                /* [SDL_MESSAGEBOX_COLOR_TEXT] */
            { 0, 255, 0 },
                /* [SDL_MESSAGEBOX_COLOR_BUTTON_BORDER] */
            { 255, 255, 255 },
                /* [SDL_MESSAGEBOX_COLOR_BUTTON_BACKGROUND] */
            { 0, 0, 0 },
                /* [SDL_MESSAGEBOX_COLOR_BUTTON_SELECTED] */
            { 255, 0, 255 }
        }
    };
    const SDL_MessageBoxData messageboxdata = {
        SDL_MESSAGEBOX_INFORMATION, /* .flags */
        NULL,                       /* .window */
        "example message box",      /* .title */
        "select a button",          /* .message */
        SDL_arraysize(buttons),     /* .numbuttons */
        buttons,                    /* .buttons */
        &colorScheme                /* .colorScheme */
    };
    int buttonid;
    if(SDL_ShowMessageBox(&messageboxdata, &buttonid) < 0) {
        SDL_Log("error displaying message box");
    }
    if(buttonid == -1) {
        SDL_Log("no selection");
    } else {
        SDL_Log("selection was %s", buttons[buttonid].text);
    }
}

void clean() {
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Comment: Try `fflush(stdout);` in-between.

Comment: See [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

Comment: I'm more looking for why this behavior is occurring.

Comment: Useful general hint: If someone gives you advice, but does not explain why, it might be a good idea to do some research on your own. That way you get more details, learn something new and very likely will memorise the information much better.

Comment: Thank you to Serikov, I did fallow up on that link and it lead me to the information I was looking for. I agree Olaf.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  The compiler will raise: `warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]` and `warning: unused parameter 'argv' [-Wunused-parameter]`.   those can be easily corrected by changing the `main()` signature to: `int main( void )`

Comment: I keep 2 version, debug and final. I do no include the warnings in the final version. I only place the build command for the final version at the top because i change the debug flags consistently. I do agree with you though user3629249

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason for the seemingly mixed output order is because in C, stdout is internally buffered.

There are only a few ways that the stdout buffer is actually flushed to the terminal.

1. a fprintf( stdout,... has the format string end in '\n'
2. similar format string considerations for printf()
3. a string item that is being output via `%s` contains a `\n`
4. the function `fflush( stdout )` is executed
5. the program tries to input anything from `stdin`
6. the program exits
7. the buffer is completely filled
8. the `setbuf()` function is called at the beginning of the program with setting the `stdout` buffer to length 0
9. the `puts()` function is called.
10. the `putc()` function is called with a char parameter of '\n'